# Remove multiple copies of folder that starts with same name using batch-file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, directory

My DESKTOP contain copies of '**CEEMEA EMEA**' folder i.e.

EMEA CEEMEA

EMEA CEEMEA - Copy

EMEA CEEMEA - Copy (2)

EMEA CEEMEA - Copy (3)

and so on

I want to delete all folders that starts with EMEA CEEMEA as file name using `CMD` or batch-file.

```
rd /s /q "%CD%\NEW FOLDER*"
```

but above command not doing anything. how does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a `For` loop with its `/D` option:

```bat
For /D %A In ("%UserProfile%\Desktop\EMEA CEEMEA*")Do @RD/S/Q "%A"
```

As you've updated your question to include batch-file, you'd change the command to this from one:

```bat
For /D %%A In ("%UserProfile%\Desktop\EMEA CEEMEA*")Do @RD/S/Q "%%A"
```

Comment: I'd prefer that you first take a look at the usage information for both of the commands used. Open a Command Prompt window and enter `For /?`, and read its content, paying additional note to its `/D` option. Next repeat the process using `RD /?`. After you've read them, if you still have any questions pertaining to this particular line of code, post back, and we'll see if we can help explain. Essentially it looks for directories, matching the wilcarded fileset in parentheses, and outputs each match, one at a time , as the metavariable `%A`, which is subsequently used in the `Do` command, `RD`.

Comment: actually I need to use this `For /D %A In ("%CD%\EMEA CEEMEA*")Do @RD/S/Q "%A"`
in `.bat` file and it does nothing.. is there anything I could change ??

Comment: It all depends upon where your batch file is located or what your current working directory is at the time the line is ran. You stated `My DESKTOP`, so I provided, the location for that. One thing is for sure, you do not need the `%CD%\ ` part, because any location which is not a fully qualified path will be taken as relative to the current directory.

Comment: you are right about `Desktop`. Problem with my command was I did not use %% percentage, now `For /D %%A In ("%CD%\EMEA CEEMEA*")Do @RD/S/Q "%%A"` is working fine.

Comment: I updated my answer, when I noticed that you'd modified your question to include the batch file requirement.